# File> Import > SVG missing

Tags: interface

[image]Anybody knows a solution? I have looked but found nothing.

Comment: That import list misses a few entries. Have you checked that the add-on is enabled in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*)?

Comment: yes, have checks next to all that should be in that list. Just does not show under list.

Comment: If this only happens with specific files, you can try unchecking *Load UI* in *File > Open* when opening the file. If this always happens you could try a factory reset (this will reset all Blender settings) *File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings*

Comment: but that is going to be a pain. I have Keen Tools installed and a reinstall of that can be a real problem.